# java CharBuffer.toString creates too many objects

Tags: java

I use CharBuffer to decode String in my application. 
But when I use CharBuffer.toString, it looks like String objects are created whenever toString method is called.
Is there any way to use string pool when I use CharBuffer?
Follwing is my method, thanks in advance.

```
private CharBuffer charbuf = CharBuffer.allocate(32000);

private String read(ByteBuffer buf, CharsetDecoder decoder)
{
    charbuf.clear();
    while (buf.remaining() > 0)
    {
        CoderResult result = decoder.decode(buf, charbuf, true);
        if (result == CoderResult.OVERFLOW)
        {
           throwInternalError();
        }
        if (result.isError())
        {
            char data = (char)buf.get();
            if (result.isUnmappable())
            {
                charbuf.put('?');
            }
            else if (result.isMalformed())
            {
                charbuf.put(data);
            }
        }
    }
    charbuf.flip();
    return charbuf.toString();
}
```

Comment: What do you want to pool? Are you repeatedly calling this method with the same `ByteBuffer` (or ByteBuffers with the same contents)

Comment: Yes, most results of read method are same. Because this method are called very offen, I like to pool results of read method.

Answer (score 1):

> It looks like `String` objects are created whenever `toString()` method is called.

Of course. That's what it's for. You could always call it less often. No point if it hasn't changed.

> Is there any way to use string pool when I use `CharBuffer`.

You could `intern()` the `Strings`. But I would leave it alone. The `Strings` will get garbage-collected in the normal course of events.